# How do i teach my students who don't have credit card

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

In few days I'm going to teach a class of more then 200 students, I will teach them how to make Alexa skills using this book(https://www.manning.com/books/voice-applications-for-alexa-and-google-assistant).

of course most of them dont have credit card because they are teen ages for making alexa skill they must have to understand how lambda function works and it is recommended to use lambda functions with alexa skill instead of simple nodejs server, so i dont want to use simple nodejs or firebase function but for working on lambda functions credit card is must, so how do I overcome this problem?

originally asked here: https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/1091...s-who-dont-have-credit-ca.html

Comment: When Amazon teaches a class they provide vouchers that you can use to sign up for an account.  Perhaps they can give you something similar that you'll make up in the cost of the class.  The vouchers have a limited value so your students aren't spinning up 100 instances to mine Bitcoin or something.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try a setup like QuikLabs where you setup your account and give students temp access.

I studied AWS using QuikLabs.